# Incorrect display of the result of executing a function to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, listener

Why does the history of moves ("listener" in Game Component (line 147)) move from top to bottom when the list moves from bottom to top?

[Full code on codepen](https://codepen.io/tre3ubec/pen/KKmPzgR)

[Tic tac toe work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8ijY.gif)

```
let listener = move
            ? stepListener(Object.values(arr[arr.length - ++move])[0], 
              Object.values(arr[arr.length - --move])[0], move)
            : 'stepListener is not working properly!'

        const desc = move
            ? `${move}. ${turn}. ${listener}`
            : 'Beginning of the game. First move.'
        return (
            <li key={move}>
                <button className="jumpTo" onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
            </li>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).